# Java synchronization private method of superclass

Tags: java, methods, synchronization, subclass

I have class A and B which inherit from Base.

Base has a private method. It is possible that A and B execute this method at the same time.

So I want to synchronize that method. If I just put "synchronize" keyword in the signature, will that make that A and B execution is synchronized (share the same lock) ? Or do I need to generate a static lock object...?

Sorry, a bit confused...

Comment: If you have different `A` and `B` objects, why does it matter if they execute the same method at the same time?

Comment: Because they are manipulating data structures of a singleton object.

Comment: so synchronize the data structures in the singleton object...

Comment: I suggest you include a short piece of code in your question to explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: People always asking for code is slowly getting on my nerves. It's a clear theory question, I just want to know what I'm asking.

Comment: @Ixx you question is not that clear (as stated in the last line). For example, if the method is private in Base, then A and B can't execute it.

Comment: They can't call it it but there's so to say one intance from Base, "in" A and other "in" B. So these classes can be executing the private method at the same time, although it was not called by them.

Comment: @Ixx for A or B to execute the private method, they need access to it, either via a protected or public method that itself calls the private method in Base.

Comment: @Ixx In the end, thread safety is about state management - to answer your question, we need to know the state space of Base, A and B (i.e. the resources they share with the rest of the world, which can be instance members, static members, network or files resources etc.).

Comment: @assylias yes, I have access to it though a public method from base. I meant that I'm not calling it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code looks a bit like the example below, then it is not thread safe and you need to include some form of synchronization to make sure the call to the private method `increment` is atomic and ensure visibility. In that simple example, making `getNewCounter` synchronized would be enough. Using a lock object would work too.

```
public class Base {
    private int counter;

    private void increment() {
        counter++;
    }
    protected int getNewCounter() {
        increment();
        return counter;
    }
}

public class A extends Base {
    public int aMethod() {
        return getNewCounter();
    }
}

public class B extends Base {
    public int anotherMethod() {
        return getNewCounter();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ixx No it isn't. See my other comment to your question. In my example, the state of Base is completely defined by the instance variable `counter`, so using the `synchronized` keyword, which locks at the instance level, is fine. If you have a static variable that you need to access in a concurrent way, then you need to lock at a static level. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve and the details of your implementation.

Comment: Well, the variable they are checking on is actually a field of the singleton... I guess I have to review this code... But well, following this discussion, this field should be handled like a static variable. You're actually right that posting code is helpful, I had to add a lot of explanations which would not have been necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Base has a private method. It is possible that A and B execute this
>   method at the same time.

Private methods or fields are not inherited by derived class, so answer to your question is no.

Edit As per comment:

If you have two objects A and B and they are trying to manipulate Singleton object C, in that case it is C which should have synchronization and not A and B.

General rule followed in multi-threaded application is, Every class which needs protection from concurrent access in order to maintain a stable state is responsible for using synchronization correctly, you shouldn't and cant expect caller of the method to access the object state in a synchronized way.

Comment: Uhm, well, but my subclass IS A Base so if Base executes the private method it's like the subclass is executing it. I can't call them in the subclass but they are executed in the context of the subclass so to say. And if I have many classes inheriting a from a class with private methods it's possible that these private methods are executed at the same time.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I first call a webservice and on the response I update the data structure. If the service has already being called I don't want to call it again. And I want to synchronize the part of the code which checks if the service has already bein called, and sets a variable that it has been already called. I want to avoid calling the webservice many times if it's not needed. Synchronozing the data structure would not help with that.

Comment: in that case you can do something like if(responseFromServer == null ) {  try { servicelock.lock(); //do operation } cathc() {} finally {servicelock.unlock();} else return responseFromServer

Comment: @lxx - You should encapsulate the call to the web service and the locking mechanism to avoid parallel calls into a new class.

Answer (score 2):

What I can understand from your post is that you have a base class with a private method. You are creating different objects of this base class or the classes derived from the base class.

Now if you make the private method syncronized It will not make the execution of that method syncronized, as you have multiple objects. Instance level lock is only per object.

For e.g. You have ObjectA and ObjectB of class Test, both these objects can execute private method say myMethod() defined in class Test simultaneously even if its synchronized because the lock is on the object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So a solution would be to have a static lock object in Base and synchronize on that.

Comment: If you simply need to check if your service is running or not, create a volatile boolean variable say isRunning. then you can check if isRunning true then do nothing else set variable tpo true and run service

Comment: That's what I want to do but I want to synchronize the code block between !isRunning() and isRunning = true, because I have to execute some other code in between :/ And I want to ensure that only 1 thread enters at the same time.

Comment: In that case yes you have to use a lock on static object. like method(){syncronized(static object){//code}}, or dont add the code in between !isRunning and isRunning=true

Answer (score 0):

What i know is that, private members are NOT inherited. So class A and class B cant access this private method with either using inheritance or creating an object of Base class to call this method, until there is a public method in Base class which has the access to this private method.